# Xamarin Forms Using multiple lists in ViewModel

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I have a problem. I created a CollectionView with a ViewModel, in that ViewModel I have 2 different Lists. Now I know how to show data from 1 list, but now I want in the datatemplate a picker with the data of the second list. Here is the xaml code:

```
<CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding imageList}">
    <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
        <GridItemsLayout Orientation="Vertical" />
    </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>

            <Picker Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.Column="3" Title="Formaat" ItemsSource="{Binding secondList}" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" />

            <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="4" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalOptions="Center"  
                    HorizontalOptions="Center" Text="{Binding Price, StringFormat='€ {0:F2}'}" TextColor="Black"
                    FontSize="18" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
</CollectionView>
```

So the Price does get shown from the imageList, but the Picker is empty. In the Picker I want the element `Name` from the `secondList`

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your `BindingContext` in the `DataTemplate` of your `CollectionView` element is an item from your `imageList`. Therefore the binding will not work, as I assume your `secondList` is not a part of the element's model that you're using in the `imageList` but rather a part of the entire view model used for the page.

I would suggest using the [`RelativeBinding`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/relative-bindings#bind-to-an-ancestor). I don't know the names of your models but your `Picker` binding could look like this:

```xml
<Picker ItemsSource="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:YourViewModelTypeName}}, Path=secondList}" />
```